# Python not inserting data's into mysql

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am testing Python and Mysql in that i am able to create and delete table's but i am unable to insert data in them.I searched stackoverflow and mostly they suggest to use

```
commit()
```

So i used it and even after i used the data is not inserted into the database.Please help me.
This is the code i use it creates the table but not inserting data

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","user","password")
cxn = MySQLdb.connect(db='test')
cursor = cxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE users(name VARCHAR(40),id VARCHAR(40))")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users(name,id) VALUES('John','1')")
db.commit()
print "Opertion completed successfully"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are `db` and `cxn` connections to the same database?

You should establish your connection using following:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                     db="test",
                     user="user",
                     passwd="password")
```

The cursor should then be derived from *this* connection via:

```
cursor = db.cursor()
```

I would hazard that your issue is coming from the ambiguity between `db` and `cxn`.